# Merging two rows and averaging the columns of those rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I merge/combine two rows with the same **ids** (row 1 and 2) and average out columns **A** and **B**. So that my dataframe would go from this:

```
   id  A   B
0  22  25  3
1  23  24  5 <-
2  23  56  3 <-
3  24  34  6
```

to this:

```
   id  A   B
0  22  25  3
1  23  40  4 <- averages of the two rows for A and B
2  24  34  6
```

Basically two rows are collapsed into one. The data in column **A** is averaged with column **A**, and column **B** is averaged with column **B**.

Comment: try this: `df.groupby('id').mean()`

Comment: @MaxU Yep! Put it as your answer. I'll mark it.

Comment: @user000001, it belongs to pandas basics, so it should be a comment at most... ;)